# Linked List on C returning NULL

Tags: c, list, struct, insert, linked-list

I've been trying to make a program that creates a list of lists (the list Groups contains two lists: transform and obj. All the code is done, but when I try to print the elements of the list, I get a NULL. I suppose the problem is in the link between the nodes of the list. Below, the function that inserts a transform (or object, the syntax is the same) to the transforms-list and the function that inserts a group to the main list. Any suggestions?

```
void insertTransform (Transform* transform, char *command, char *command2)
{
     Transform * newTransform = (Transform*) malloc(sizeof(Transform));
     newTransform->k = findKey(command);
     newTransform->ttype = command;
     newTransform->param = command2;
     if (transform==NULL)
     {
         transform=newTransform;
         transform->next=NULL;
     }
     else
     {
         newTransform->next=transform;
         transform=newTransform;
     }
}

void insertGroup (Group* group, Transform *transform, Obj *obj)
{
     Group * newGroup = (Group*) malloc(sizeof(Group));
     newGroup->t = transform;
     newGroup->obj = obj;
     newGroup->next=group;
     group=newGroup;
}
```

Comment: Both these functions return void. And both fail to hand their allocated stuff to their caller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to either pass your list head by address (a pointer to pointer) or return the new list head from your function. I prefer the former of these, as it lets me return real error codes from the function rather than just a NULL.

Tackling these in reverse order:

```
int insertGroup (Group** group, Transform *transform, Obj *obj)
{
     Group * newGroup = malloc(sizeof(Group));
     if (newGroup == NULL)
     {
         perror("Failed to allocate new group");
         return -1;
     }

     newGroup->t = transform;
     newGroup->obj = obj;
     newGroup->next=*group;
     *group=newGroup;
     return 0;
}
```

Invoked as

```
Group *grp = NULL;
if (insertGroup(&grp, transform, obj) != 0)
{
     // error condition
}
```

Transforms are similarly handled:

```
int insertTransform (Transform** transform, char *command, char *command2)
{
     Transform * newTransform = malloc(sizeof(Transform));
     if (newTransform == NULL)
     {
         perror("Failed to allocate new transform");
         return -1;
     }

     newTransform->k = findKey(command);
     newTransform->ttype = command;
     newTransform->param = command2;
     newTransform->next = *transform;
     *transform = newTransform;
     return 0;
}
```

And again, invoked as:

```
Transform *tfrm = NULL;
if (insertTransform(&tfrm, cmd1, cmd2) != 0)
{
    // error condition
}
```

Hope that gets you going.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void insertGroup (Group* group, Transform *transform, Obj *obj)
{
     Group * newGroup = (Group*) malloc(sizeof(Group));
     newGroup->t = transform;
     newGroup->obj = obj;
     newGroup->next=NULL;
     group->next=newGroup;
}
```

This assumes that the group passed in is the current head and your trying to add the new node at the end.

Or do this to insert at the beginning:

```
void insertGroup (Group* group, Transform *transform, Obj *obj)
{
     Group * newGroup = (Group*) malloc(sizeof(Group));
     newGroup->t = transform;
     newGroup->obj = obj;
     newGroup->next= group->next;
     group->next=newGroup;
}
```